# How can I clone/pull/push github repository using jquery or any javascript library?

Tags: javascript, github-api

I need to clone github repo and do pull/push using only javascript. I couldn't find a good library which is easy to use for this. Any recommendations?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

you mean this one ? help you to create a solution talk with github by javascript.

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/github-api

Comment: I tried using this api. I wanted the api itself to download the files (for cloning) into specified local directory, rather this api returns json only. Is it possible to download the files to local machine using this api?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this one is not bad; the only bad thing is it uses Jquery which I not prefer to use, but seems doesn't have any other option.

https://github.com/k33g/gh3